# Rails HABTM order with select boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, many-to-many

I have two models (code redacted for clarity):

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :products
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :apps
end
```

I want to be able to add multiple products to each app. Also, the order of the products in the app is important, and where I'm having trouble.

I'm using simple_form and I've tried using the association method:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@app) do |form| %>
  <%= form.input :name %>
  <%= form.association :products %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

It works wonderfully, but the select box it creates is not orderable. My attempt at a solution was to create multiple `<select>` boxes and order them somehow. This so far isn't working. As a test I tried this:

```
<%= form.collection_select('product_ids', Product.all, :id, :name, {}, {name: 'app[product_ids][]'}) %>
<%= form.collection_select('product_ids', Product.all, :id, :name, {}, {name: 'app[product_ids][]'}) %>
<%= form.collection_select('product_ids', Product.all, :id, :name, {}, {name: 'app[product_ids][]'}) %>
<%= form.collection_select('product_ids', Product.all, :id, :name, {}, {name: 'app[product_ids][]'}) %>
```

It actually does make the association in the database, but it 'selects' all the products for each select tag which ends up just selecting the last product on all of them:

```
<select id="app_product_ids" name="app[product_ids][]">
  <option selected="selected" value="1">Golf Club</option>
  <option value="20">Music Disc</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="17">Magic Wand</option>
  <option value="15">Nike Running Shoes</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="19">Watch</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="16">Wooden Spoon</option> // this is what is selected in the browser
</select>
```

Eventually, I'll make the adding and removal of these dynamic.

So my question is, how can I make this work? One way would be to have each `<select>` associate to the particular product instead of all the products. Maybe there's a better way all together.